# how to add background image to lightning

Tags: lightning, images

I want to add background image, to part of my header i wrote code like this. 
but its not working.

```
<div style="{!'background:' + v.backgroundColor + ' url(' + v.backgroundImageURL +') no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size: cover;'}">

</div>
```

---

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var url = $A.get('$Resource.RollingHillsGrey1');
        component.set('v.backgroundImageURL', url);
    }
```

Comment: I personally think this is a much better way to apply styling to your div https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm

Comment: @Rao That won't work for dynamic images, but you're right that you should *prefer* to use this technique when possible.

Comment: point noted fox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify some content and/or a height in order for this to work. I tweaked your code slightly to display the image as a background image:

```
<div style="{!'position: relative; height: 30vh; background:' + v.backgroundColor + ' url(' + v.backgroundImageURL +') no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size: cover;'}">

</div>
```